# Name of default "sffamily" font

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I'm using LaTeX (texlive) in Debian Wheezy. How can I determine which font is specified by `\sffamily`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could issue `\meaning\sfdefault` in the document body -- without any font packages loaded, this will yield `cmss`, i.e., Computer Modern Sans Serif.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\meaning\sfdefault

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, this yields `\long macro:->cmss`. Thanks.